Docker build hangs on downloading model shards using transformers in a Flask application
I am trying to containerize a Flask application that uses the transformers library to load a BLIP model. The application works fine locally, but when I try to build the Docker image, the process hangs at the model downloading step.
Objective
My objective is to create a Dockerfile that runs the following Flask application:
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from utils import load_blip_model, generate_caption

# Load the BLIP model
processor, model = load_blip_model()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    if "image" not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No image part in the request"}), 400

    file_storage = request.files["image"]
    image_path = "temp_image.jpg"
    file_storage.save(image_path)

    generated_text = generate_caption(model, processor, image_path)
    os.remove(image_path)

    return jsonify({"caption": generated_text})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)


The load_blip_model function in utils.py is defined as:
from transformers import AutoProcessor, Blip2ForConditionalGeneration, BitsAndBytesConfig

def load_blip_model():
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b")
    quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_8bit_fp32_cpu_offload=True, device_map="auto")
    model = Blip2ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
        "Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b",
        quantization_config=quantization_config
    )
    return processor, model


Dockerfile

FROM nvidia/cuda:12.1.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    wget build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev \
    libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev \
    libffi-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libexpat1-dev libglib2.0-0 \
    libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx patch git tree \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.10.14
RUN cd /usr/src && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz && \
    cd Python-$PYTHON_VERSION && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared && \
    make -j $(nproc) && make altinstall && ldconfig

# Install pip
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3.10 get-pip.py && rm get-pip.py

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3.10 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
CMD ["python3.10", "blip-server.py"]

Issue
The build successfully completes with:
 docker build -t blip:v1 .
And is run with:
 docker run --gpus all -p 5000:5000 blip:v1
However, it hangs at this step :
Downloading shards:   0%|          | 0/2 [01:07<?, ?it/s]

I tried to preload the model into the Docker image during the build by adding this line to the Dockerfile:
RUN python3 -c "from transformers import AutoProcessor, Blip2ForConditionalGeneration; AutoProcessor.from_pretrained('Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b'); Blip2ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b')"

But now it  hangs at the model downloading step when building the docker image. Why does this happen ?

try docker run --network=host to use host network

@TanThien it didn't fixe the issue
